# Unable to connect to SQL Server from Docker container (Linux image)

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, containers

In our application we are using linux based container which access SQL server installed on VM. Everything works fine in local environment outside the container, But when I ran the app in local container we are getting the below error.

"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught"

```
appsetings.json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    
    "DbConnection": "Server=tcp:vmname\\sqlservername,49763;Database=dbname;User ID=username_Users;Password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=False;"
  }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
.......
```

Any inputs will be appreciated

Comment: So the real question is how to connect to a named SQL Server instance from Linux using ADO.NET? Is the server configured to use SSL?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, it is configured to use SSL and I have configured root CA in the linux image

Comment: and we are using Entityframework

Answer (score 2):

Please add **;TrustServerCertificate=true** to your connection string.

Comment: Tried that , same issue. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @SijoX did you solve this? I am facing the same error. Thanks.

Comment: @John see SijoX's answer above. Apparently, upgrading TLS 1.2 resolved the issue.

Comment: @John yes , upgrading TLS version solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to TLS version of the SQL server, enabling TLS 1.2 resolved the issue